# Call element.click() failed in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, mobile

I use this ajax call in a single js file, and import this in the jsf page I was using.

I debug this part in Chrome, I set a break point before the $("#close").click(); then I type this in the console, it comes out the element's html code, but it will not click that button, please help, what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
function doLogin(username, password) {
$.ajax({
    "type" : "post",
    "url" : "com.micros.hcp.mobile.ajax.common.AjaxMSMLoginDialog.ajax",
    data : {
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password
    },
    dataType : "text",
    async: false,
    error : function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        notification("Login failed.");
    },
    success : function(data) {
        data = String(data).trim();
        if (data == "login_success") {
            alert($("#close").attr("id")); // make sure I can get the element
            $("#close").click();
        } else {
            addErrorMessage(data);
        }
    }
});
}
```

below is the result showing in the chrome console when I input $("close").click();  at the break point.After the Ajax call, if I run this in the console, it works.

```
$("#close").click();
[
<a href=​"#" id=​"close" data-role=​"button" data-rel=​"back" style=​"display:​ none;​ " data-          corners=​"true" data-shadow=​"true" data-iconshadow=​"true" data-wrapperels=​"span" data-theme=​"c" class=​"ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" data-transition=​"slideup" data-    direction=​"reverse">​…​</a>​
]
```

Comment: Do you have any click events on the anchor tag? None are visible that I can see in your code...

Comment: You need to define it ` $("#close").click(function(){alert('clicked');});`

Comment: Yes I have, sorry didn't paste it here. I have this inside the form

Comment: <a href="#" id="close" data-role="button" data-rel="back"></a>

Comment: @XinshanBai : change it to `<a href="#" id="close" data-role="button" data-rel="back" click='callJSFunction()'></a>`

Answer (score -1):

define a JS function:

```
function clicked(){
    alert('clicked');
}
```

add the `onclick` attribute to your `<a></a>` element

```
<a href=​"#" id=​"close" data-role=​"button" data-rel=​"back" style=​"display:​ none;​ " data-          corners=​"true" data-shadow=​"true" data-iconshadow=​"true" data-wrapperels=​"span" data-theme=​"c" class=​"ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" data-transition=​"slideup" data-    direction=​"reverse" onclick="clicked()">​…​</a>​
```

then it will fire your custom function with this"

```
$('#close').click();
```

Comment: but what will it trigger if OP doesnot have any click function binded to the anchor tag ?

Comment: `$('#close').click()` IS same as `$('#close').trigger('click');`

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I tried the trigger before, but didn't have the bind part, now I did as you said, but it still does not work....the clicked showed when the trigger is executed, but the dialog is not closed. The button is used for closing the dialog.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question, you have to add the `onClick` attribute to you `<a></a>` element, see the updated answer.

Comment: I did, I change it to <a href="#" id="close" data-role="button" data-rel="back" onclick="clicked()"></a> but the clicked still popped out as a alert, if I run $("#close").trigger('click'); in the console it still says ReferenceError: clicked is not defined, looks like it can't recognize the clicked()

Comment: omg... that is not the problem, I am sorry, what I posted here is not the point, I resolved the problem, it is because I was calling this method through a validate function, after the function it will refresh the page... But really thank you~